# Авторизация в VK с помощью requests

Tags: python, авторизация, requests

Хочу авторизоваться на сайте vk.com и получить html своей страницы.
В запросе передаю логин/пароль как параметры формы.

```
r = requests.get('http://vk.com/',params={'email':'login','pass':'password'})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

На что получаю html с предложение пройти авторизацию.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, на основании чего вы такой код написали.

Но для авторизации в VK использует oauth, читаем [доки](https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile).

Answer (score 4):

```
import lxml.html
import requests

login = 'твой логин'
password = 'твой пароль'
url = 'https://vk.com/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'DNT':'1'
}
session = requests.session()
data = session.get(url, headers=headers)
page = lxml.html.fromstring(data.content)

form = page.forms[0]
form.fields['email'] = login
form.fields['pass'] = password

response = session.post(form.action, data=form.form_values())
print('onLoginDone' in response.text)
```